# Aggregate and sum a dataframe

Tags: r

I want to aggregate over a dataframe, and sum it up by category. I have this

```
my_basket = data.frame(ITEM_GROUP = c("Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Fruit","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Vegetable","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy","Dairy"),
                       ITEM_NAME = c("Apple","Banana","Orange","Mango","Papaya","Carrot","Potato","Brinjal","Raddish","Milk","Curd","Cheese","Milk","Paneer"),
                       Price = c(100,80,80,90,65,70,60,70,25,60,40,35,50,120),
                       Tax = c(2,4,5,6,2,3,5,1,3,4,5,6,4,3))
aggregate(x = my_basket[3,], by = list(my_basket[1,]), FUN = sum)
```

But it gives me an error telling me that

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(x = my_basket[3, ], by = list(my_basket[1,  :
> arguments must have same length
> Calls:  ->  -> aggregate -> aggregate.data.frame
> Execution halted

How should I reference the column by index?

I am new to R, and i think i dont quite get how to reference a dataframe by column. All examples i see uses names. I can't narrow my search well enough, therefore this question.

Comment: Do you want: `aggregate(x = my_basket[3], by = my_basket[1], FUN = sum)` ?

Comment: I knew it was simple (but i have tried so many iterations over this that my mind is blown away). Thanks. Please create an answer, and i will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `[1,]` you are subsetting rows and not columns. With `[,1]` you select the first column as a vector. With `[1]` you select the first column as a data.frame.

```
aggregate(x = my_basket[3], by = my_basket[1], FUN = sum)
#  ITEM_GROUP Price
#1      Dairy   305
#2      Fruit   415
#3  Vegetable   225
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also use formula method in `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Price ~ ITEM_GROUP, my_basket, FUN = sum)
```